# No longer able to login to the control panel

Tags: structure, login

I'm having trouble logging into a site I'm building. I get no username/password errors when I try to login, but the cp login screen persists. exp_cp_log shows that I'm logged in.

EE 2.6.1

The last thing I did before I logged out was enable structure(3.3.8), although I'm not sure if that's the culprit.

Things I've tried:

1. clear cache
2. restart
3. different browsers
4. cleared the exp_sessions table
5. turned on dubug

No luck trying these solutions out either:

[Login page returns to the login page, doesn't log me in?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/398/login-page-returns-to-the-login-page-doesnt-log-me-in/403#403)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know [Structure](http://buildwithstructure.com) has updated (version 3.3.10) since EE 2.6 was released. Try updating Structure and see what you get.

If that doesn't work, could it be that you've been bitten by this bug? Give the fix a try. https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19334

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Stephen. I'm looking into both of these now. I'll update this with what I find. Much appreciated.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest Structure version worked. Thanks, Stephen.

Comment: Glad to hear it.