# Upgraded to EE 4.2.0 from EE 3.5.15 and now can't login

Tags: login

Upgraded to EE 4.2.0 from EE 3.5.15 and now can't login to the backend

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more information? Do you see any errors? Does the site work as intended? Can you try other user accounts? Check the config file for any errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login page returns to the login page, doesn't log me in?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/398/login-page-returns-to-the-login-page-doesnt-log-me-in)

Answer (score 1):

Generally it happens in EE4 when you have your ID row in **exp_members** table but not in **exp_member_data** table. Can you make sure you have entry in both the table?

Comment: Seems to be a problem when running the site on local, was ok when I uploaded a copy onto a server. Not sure what problem was exactly

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines on the bottom of your system/user/config/config.php file:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_path'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['user_session_type'] = 'c';
$config['admin_session_type'] = 's';
```

Comment: Nice one Max. This worked for me after a migration and an upgrade...